# First fit algorithm

Tags: algorithm, operating-system, system

Lets say I have a Variable Partitioning with free space: at address 32k a free space of 8k, and at address 15k a free space of size 11k.

I need to create a first fit free table.

Am I doing the right thing?

```
+--------+-------+
|address | size  | 
|32      |8      |
|15      |11     |
+--------+-------+
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basically, yes, that's correct.

Although, unless you want your allocation function to only work with multiples of 1K, you may want to store the byte addresses and counts, eg, 32K is 32,768.

Comment: Thank you, is it the same for the best fit?

Comment: @Art, the information will be the same though it may be organised differently, for efficiency. Example, you may want a tree structure so you can quickly locate the smallest usable block, as well as sorting by address so you can combine adjacent free blocks.

Answer (score 0):

yes. It looks correct. When you have more number of free spaces you can find the first fit using winner tree.